# Recursively adding ellipses to a Pane

Tags: java, recursion, javafx

I am trying to recursively add ellipses to a pane for homework. I have written what  code I believe should work, and while it both compiles and runs, it shows nothing on my pane.For a little background, the ellipses should all be centered in the pane, each should be 10px away from the next ellipse edge, and the outer ellipse should be 10px away from the edge of the pane.

Here is my code

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class DisplayCircles extends Application {

    private static Pane mainPane = new Pane();

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        double horRadius = (mainPane.getWidth() / 2) - 10;
        double vertRadius = (mainPane.getHeight() / 2) - 10;
        addCircles(horRadius, vertRadius);
        Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane, 500, 500);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Circle Display");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    /**
     * Recursively adds circles to the pane from largest to smallest.
     *
     * @param horizontal - The starting horizontal radius.
     * @param vertical - The starting vertical radius.
     */
    public static void addCircles(double horizontal, double vertical) {

        if (horizontal <= 10 || vertical <= 10) {

            createEllipse(horizontal, vertical);

        } else {

            createEllipse(horizontal, vertical);
            addCircles(horizontal - 10, vertical - 10);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Creates an ellipse with the given horizontal and vertical radii.
     *
     * @param horizontal - The x based radius.
     * @param vertical - the y based radius.
     */
    private static void createEllipse(double horizontal, double vertical) {

        Random rand = new Random();
        Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse(horizontal, vertical);
        ellipse.centerXProperty().bind(
            mainPane.widthProperty().divide(2.0));
        ellipse.centerYProperty().bind(
            mainPane.heightProperty().divide(2.0));
        double r = rand.nextDouble();
        double g = rand.nextDouble();
        double b = rand.nextDouble();
        double o = rand.nextDouble();
        ellipse.setFill(Color.color(r, g, b, o));
        mainPane.getChildren().add(ellipse);

    }

}
```

Comment: Through a quick shower, i realized that one issue is that I needed to half my pane width and heights before subtracting the first 10px in order to make the ellipse stay within my pane. I still do not have anything appearing within my pane. I am unsure why this is. I have made a face with geometric shapes and things of that nature. I am unsure why these ellipses are not showing up.

Comment: You probably need something like `mainPane.repaint()` or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width and height of the `Pane` will be `0` until it has been added to a `Scene` and that `Scene` has undergone layout. Of course, in this case you know what the initial size of the pane is going to be, so you can do

```
    double width = 500 ;
    double height = 500 ;
    double horRadius = (width / 2) - 10;
    double vertRadius = (height / 2) - 10;
    addCircles(horRadius, vertRadius);
    Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane, width, height);
```

Another solution would be to re-compute the graphics when the size of the pane changes. In this solution, the circles are drawn when the pane is first placed in the scene, and then redrawn to fill the pane any time the window resizes. This probably isn't what you want for this application, but might be a useful idea in other cases:

```
    mainPane.boundsInLocalProperty().addListener((obs, oldBounds, newBounds) -> {
        mainPane.getChildren().clear();
        double horRadius = (mainPane.getWidth() / 2) - 10;
        double vertRadius = (mainPane.getHeight() / 2) - 10;
        addCircles(horRadius, vertRadius);
    });
    Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane, 500, 500);
```

As an aside, why did you make everything `static`? It doesn't matter too much as only one instance of an `Application` subclass is ever created, but in general it's bad practice to use `static` when there's no good design reason to do so.

Comment: Wow, that was a very minor yet fairly obvious fix. Thanks. As for the static. It became a bad habit that I am actually trying to thwart from when i began programming. I started just adding it because of the times that I would call a method and would receive an error saying that I couldn't call a non static method in a static manner. Now that I have a better understanding overall, I am slowly trying to lose the habit. Thanks for pointing it out so that I can remedy that. Hadn't noticed that I was doing it this time.

Comment: Updated answer with another option. On `static`: I usually tell beginning programmers that, while there are lots of good uses for it, anything beyond using it in a `main(...)` method and for declaring constants should be considered at least a moderately advanced topic. (So keep trying to kick the habit :).)